# DataGridCell BorderBrush not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcell

I tried to set `DataGridCell` `BorderBrush`, but it looks like there is some other setting, which also sets border between cells.
Current `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>
```

It looks like this:
[image: Yellow and black border]
I don't want that black border there. I want just the yellow border. Can someone please point me, where can I set the "black" border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid has additional properties for grid lines

try set Yellow color for both

```
VerticalGridLinesBrush="Yellow"    
HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Yellow"
```

or hide them

```
GridLinesVisibility="None"
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.